# Symfony 4 - FOSUserBundle - Template on custom route

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle, symfony4

Symfony 4 app using the FOSUserBundle.

I have made custom sub routes for the user profile (eg. profile/bookings), and I have added some custom fields to the user entity (firstName and lastName).

If I reference `{{ user.firstName }}` in my twig template on a custom route (non FOSUserBundle route), I get a 'User entity not found' error.

How do I access the properties of the user in the twig template?

Comment: {{ app.user.firstName }} should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are rendering your view, from your controller, you can pass datas to the twig template using an array in the second parameter of the `render()` method.

This array is used this way : `array('TwigVariableName' => $someValue, 'AnotherTwigVariable' => $someOtherValue)`

In example :

```
//This is a controller
public function bookings()
{
    //get the current user
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')
                 ->getToken()
                 ->getUser();

    //Or, simplier, since we are in a controller :
    $user = $this->getUser();

    return ($this->render('bookings.html.twig', array('user' => $user)));
}
```

---

**Or**

As stated Cerad in comments, you can directly access in Twig the current user, using `{{ app.user.firstName }}`

Comment: Ok so how do I get the user? do I typehint User into the bookings() method? do i use a constructor?

Comment: Which user is it? The current one?

Comment: if it's current user (logged in user) you can access it whithin controller via `$this->getUser()`. Outside a controller you'll have to inject the `Security` service `$this->security->getUser()`

Comment: Yes app.user.firstName worked, just wondering if this only works for User entity or other entities in the doctrine database as well?

Comment: You need to send datas in the view like I did in the first example.